# Stop execution of a function after a given time in PHP

Tags: linux, php, timeout, exec

I have five `exec()` functions in my script. I want to set it up so that if a function fails to respond in a given time, the function will be killed and the next function will start its execution.

```
<?php
    exec("timeout 5 /usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$uptime);  
    exec("timeout 5 /usr/local/bin/trun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$uptime);  
    exec("timeout 5 /usr/local/bin/drun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$uptime);
 ?>
```

In this the `timeout` argument is not working. Please correct this or give me an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

your exec sysntax is wrong

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

You have to set time limit before you begin your code,
something like this

```
<?php

set_time_limit(5);

exec(" /usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$uptime);
?>
```